# Add function to tablesorter (jQuery plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

My English is not good, sorry...

I use tablesorter (tablesorter.com) to sort table in web site.

Please help me add a function to this plugin. I create function, but I don't know how to add my function to tablesorter

Regards,

Paris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(document).ready(function() 
    {

$("#myTable").tablesorter(function(){

```
     //your  functionality code here
```

}); 
    } 
);

Comment: not even in English ..even the spelling of "English" also .edit it .